# Magento 2 amazon pay not working as expected only on product page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, amazon, amazon-payment

Magento 2.3.0 I already set the configuration for Amazon seller and **all working well except product page**.

Minicart button and product page button not working on the product page. But on another page **mini cart button working well**.

What can I do? How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For "Allowed Return URLs" in the integration center make sure to include

https://www.yourdomain.com/**amazon/login/processAuthHash/**

Give it some time (up to 48h) for Amazon to update the URL setttings and then it should work on the product pages.